# Grok pattern for data separated by pipe with whitespaces and optional values in it

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a textfile/logfile in which the values are separated by a pipe symbol. "|" with multiple whitespaces.

Also I just wanted to try it without gsub.

An example is below,

Does anyone know how to write a GROK pattern to extract it for logstash? as I am very new to it. Thanks in advance

```
5000|       |       |applicationLog     |ClientLog      |SystemLog      |Green      |       |2014-01-07 11:58:48.76948      |12345 (0x1224)|1) Error 2)Sample Log | Configuration Manager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of `|` are inconsistent between different words, you can match it with `.*?` and extract rest of the data as [predefined grok pattern](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)

```
%{NUMBER:num}.*?%{WORD:2nd}.*?%{WORD:3rd}.*?%{WORD:4th}.*?%{WORD:5th}.*?%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}
```

which will give you,

```
{
  "num": [
    [
      "5000"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "5000"
    ]
  ],
  "2nd": [
    [
      "applicationLog"
    ]
  ],
  "3rd": [
    [
      "ClientLog"
    ]
  ],
  "4th": [
    [
      "SystemLog"
    ]
  ],
  "5th": [
    [
      "Green"
    ]
  ],
  "TIMESTAMP_ISO8601": [
    [
      "2014-01-07 11:58:48.76948"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2014"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "01"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "07"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "11",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "58",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "48.76948"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can test it at [online grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Since you are new to `grok` you might want to read, [grok filter plugin basics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

If you can, I'd suggest you to also have a look in [dissect filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) which is faster and efficient than `grok`,

> The Dissect filter is a kind of split operation. Unlike a regular
>   split operation where one delimiter is applied to the whole string,
>   this operation applies a set of delimiters to a string value. Dissect
>   does not use regular expressions and is very fast. However, if the
>   structure of your text varies from line to line then Grok is more
>   suitable. There is a hybrid case where Dissect can be used to
>   de-structure the section of the line that is reliably repeated and
>   then Grok can be used on the remaining field values with more regex
>   predictability and less overall work to do.